# Datetime base parameter's fetch data issue on the bases on format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, ado.net

I'm fetching records from the db on the bases of one datetime type field. But the formate i'm saving in the db is like "2013-04-09 15:02:46.803". when i send the parameter of datetime to select record is like '4/9/2013 3:07:26 PM'. Actually i'm try to use both like and equal in condition but both not working. As the format of a date should same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your condition need to compare time as well as date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact() to string in format ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ff") you need and pass data as a string value. But you have to change your ExecuteTag second parameter from DateTime to string

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the dates to float and then compare

```
select ......
where cast(a.UpdatedOn as float) = cast(cast('4/9/2013 3:07:26 PM' as datetime) as float)
```